# Windows phone xaml style inside a style?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, textbox, styling, autocompletebox

I am trying to style the textbox property for the Autocompletebox in xaml for windows phone 8, I have managed to add the autocompletebox's style in my page resources, but I want to edit the textbox control inside the auto completebox's style, to another textboxstyle on my page, however it is not working what am I doing wrong,

thanx

code:

```
....
 <Style TargetType="Controls:AutoCompleteBox" x:Name="AutoCompleteTemplate">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="45" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Controls:AutoCompleteBox">
                    <Grid Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}">
                        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}"/> <!--code not working-->
....

style for textbox (which does work have tried it on normal textbox )

  <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionForeground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="CaretBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxReadOnlyBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBorderBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="MainBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"/>
                        <Border x:Name="ReadonlyBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: what exception is it throwing ?

Comment: COM reference, so something in my xaml is wrong

Comment: {System.Exception: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)}

Comment: This above error occurs because of corrupted Cache of Visual Studio. In order to resolve the issue just try deleteing the project Cache.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio X\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache

C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio X\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache

Comment: Then run "devenv.exe /setup" to re-build the cache.

Start—>Run—> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio X\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe  /setup

Comment: this doesn't work, I have a textbox inside my autocompletebox style for controltemplate, which I am trying to set that's my problem, how do I fix this

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I just found a solution, by setting the color in codebehind works fine, not having to struggle with the styling templates etc

```
 private void autobxCountry_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        autobxCountry.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        autobxCountry.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    }
```